# Cultural effects of visible light perceived as travelling at 10 m/s

Tags: culture, science-in-society

Light moves the same, but the human eye instead perceives light as travelling at 10 meters per second. That means light still moves at it's universal constant, but humans see light as though it was slower.

To clarify, humans always saw it this way until the 1850s, when people started seeing light normally.

How is human culture right up until then affected by the fact that everyone saw light as slower than it really is?

Also what would the average reaction be when people start suddenly see light at normal speed at the beginning of the 1850s?

Comment: "how would the world react... " is the archetype of opinion based question. Please modify the question (I tried to improve its structure, but cannot go further) to remove this aspect, else it will be closed.

Comment: "End of the universe as we know it, everyone dead" doesn't sound like an interesting story. Why do you want to build such world?

Comment: Changing a fundamental constant of the universe will fundamentally change the universe. It is safe to say that the effects of this change are too broad for a reasonable question. I am voting to close as too broad.

Comment: I agree that this question is too broad, but it has the makings of a very interesting question if it can be suitably focused.

Comment: Changed it. Is this a better edit?

Comment: Nope. "The universal speed limit there is the same as in our universe, light is just slower." makes electricity not work the way it is working, or makes light not an EM wave. From too broad, you changed it to "it's pure magic, nothing makes sense, so nothing has t make sense". Forgive me if it sounded harsh, English is not my first language and I don't know how to re-word this.

Comment: Does this work?

Comment: The problem is there are two interconnected issues. One aspect (which I suspect you are interested in) focuses on how humans would react if everything worked the same except light was delayed in arriving. The second more problematic one is what effect would changing a fundamental constant of nature have? For example changing the speed of light would affect the relationship between mass and energy E=Mc2. I can try rewriting it if you like.

Comment: Yes, please do that.

Comment: I'm going to completely rewrite the question.

Comment: Check my rewrite. Feel free to change it back, I know it's not realy the same question now but I think it has a flavour of what you were asking and it avoids the universal constant of nature being changed problem.

Comment: Check out the new edit. I realised the questions of things like nature being changed and the like were being asked because when my unrevised post got edited, the person who did it misunderstood my question. I am asking how would human culture be affected if visible light ALWAYS traveled at 10 m/s, until 1850, at which it traveled at c, like every other spectrum.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say. The problem is getting at the aspect you are interested in without changing the whole universe. It sounds rather odd, but if light did travel at 10m/s it would affect much more than you think. Changing c in anyway hits a sort of physics raw nerve. I suggest we try rewriting it until we get some better feedback then I will ask if it can be reopened.

Comment: Well, by all means, rewrite it again, if you think it'll help. If we must, you can move this to chat.

Comment: Know what, just edit this as you please. I'll probably be back later in the day.

Comment: OK done. I think this version might stand a chance. I will see what I can do to get it reopened.

Comment: You might want to drop this question in the sandbox and work from there, https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4835/sandbox-for-proposed-questions

Comment: Why was my question changed to back to pre-last edit? I'm fixing it.

Comment: @GiantSpacePeanut Why do you want this? Does your world critically hinge upon this concept or are you exploring a "What if..." that you came up with?

Comment: I'm here to explore a what if. I'm mainly here because i was told at a subreddit called /r/hypothetical situation that this question would make a good question there. So far it seems as though no matter how i have tried to ask it it is not the correct way to not be on hold. So i'm letting this question, post and site go, because it's taking much more dedication than i expected.

Answer (score 2):

## Light speed only appears to change

Much depends on how this appearance of change takes place. We do not know of any way in which light gets changed the farther it travels, but we might posit first a real effect similar to fog, that changes how light is transmitted; then a perceptual change linked to the previous one, introducing a perceptual delay.

This requires extensive modifications of the whole visual system, that needs to become something like a FIFO queue. The farther object we can see in everyday's life might be, say, one kilometer out (we place a cap on the effect at this distance). At 10 m/s that's one minute forty seconds, which means that the visual cue reaches the beholder at t=0 and is only perceived 1'40" later; the visual system must "store" at least two minutes' worth of images.

Perception of simultaneity would crash.

Objects coming towards the observer at more than 10 m/s would not be perceived until they hit, and then they would be perceived *in reverse*, as perception catches up with their position, or moving at ludicrous speeds.

```
Example: I am 20m from you, I start moving at 35.999 km/h towards you
on my bike. You see me moving after 1.998 seconds, and 0.002 seconds
later I hit you. So you "see" me driving 20m in 2 milliseconds, or at
an apparent velocity of 10 km/s.
```

## Pre-update answer: light speed does change

It is difficult to answer this question *correctly*. Visible light is light is electromagnetic radiation, so changing the nature of visible light has far-reaching consequences.

And when you factor in that the nuclear reactions in the Sun's core are kept in equilibrium by light pressure (amongst other things) and a significant part of that is in the visible range, you begin to see just how momentous those consequences might be. Depending on the case, the Sun might go nova, or simply fizzle out.

Closer to home, though, "visible light" is what feeds plant life through photosynthesis (and several other reactions also have energies in that range). Photons in visible light having different speed means they'd have a different energy; more than eight order of magnitude less, which means that chlorophyll no longer works, and vegetable life disappears, with animal life and oxygen soon to follow.

The closest you might come to this scenario is atmosphere being contaminated by a cosmic cloud of unobtainium, which while being biologically inert and roughly the same density as air, it has an unreasonable refractive index in the *billions* (for comparison, water has 1.333).

This magic gas is not easily miscible in either water or lipids, which means that it stays out of people's bodies. *Inside* the body everything is normal. Outside, visible light is slowed down, but not material objects; they travel in a "bubble" that displaces air, a sort of Alcubierre propulsion all of their own.

We have to thoroughly handwave away the problem of different densities of unobtainium giving rise to different refractive zones, because it would have the effect of walking through a House of Mirrors, only several orders of magnitude crazier.

The sky would appear to be a perfect mirror, since the [internal reflection angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_internal_reflection#Critical_angle) is now practically 0° (outgoing visible light passes from refractive index of 30,000,000 to the refractive index of vacuum). This translates to a considerable greenhouse effect.

And there will be now significant signal delay in the sense of sight.

Now here two strange(r) thing happen. One is that the effect might not be exactly flat across the whole spectrum. Red light might be slowed down more than blue light. This would mean that farther objects's blue light would reach us before their red light, transforming vision into a [psychedelic experience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nude_Descending_a_Staircase,_No._2) where a distant runner dressed in white appears as a continuous series of time-phased runners dressed in all the shades of the rainbow.

The other thing unfortunately is that any movement within the unobtainium cloud at more than the critical velocity of 36 km per hour will be accompanied by a power loss, said power being transformed into a [harmless (?) blue light halo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherenkov_radiation).

Likewise, the air-unobtainium mix will rapidly dissipate sound waves, as they make the air vibrate at 330 m/s, but the handwavium component of the mix cannot take it - it will absorb the impacts and re-radiate them as Cherenkov radiation.

Unless by some magic quantum effect the refractive index is *really* steeply sloped and falls towards tolerable values just outside the visible spectrum, or by some even more magic effect this doesn't *a*ffect motion; thereby **allowing matter a higher speed than light in the same material** (this does not happen for anything else that I know of, except carefully constructed metamaterials and in a very specific, non-isotropic way - not at all what we need with our unobtainium).

If the "speed of light in unobtainium" limit behaves like the speed of light in any other matter, then we have slowed down light -- but in so doing, we have effectively killed all sounds.

And at this point it finally comes to me that when interfering with particle velocity, lack of sound is the last of our problems, as this would also affect the *thermal velocity of air particles*. Thermal equilibrium at thermal velocities of 10 m/s happens far, far below zero.

Comment: I think you have hit the nail on the head over what the problem is and your suggestion might be even better than mine - see rewrite - sorry this has been on going while you were preparing your answer, but I think the question was/is in danger of being closed due to the problems you outlined.